# Does every tool or feature in Blender have a keyboard shortcut or hotkey?

Tags: shortcut, tools

Is there a shortcut hotkey for every tool or task in Blender?

Comment: Not everything, but most things. You can download a shortcut reference sheet (created by Andrew Price - the blender guru) here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3j61d896my0v8e5/Blender%20Cheatsheet%20v1.pdf

Comment: Also F3 key (mouse on the Viewport) is a good way to see most of the shortcuts

Comment: if you want to give a shortcut to an operation that has not, you can right click on this operation and Add to Quick Favorites, then to activate press Q